# File uploading to /tmp, rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I want to upload an file to /tmp folder, then use it in controller. But a file do not goes from view to controller.
Look my view:

```
<% form_tag import_cash_payments_forms_path, {:method => :post, :multipart => true} do %>
    <b>city:</b>
    <%= select :data, :city_id, @cities %>
    <br>
    <br>
    <b>region:</b>
    <%= select :data, :region_id, @regions %>
    <br>
    <br>
    <b>date:</b>
    <%= date_select2 :data, :date %>
    <br>
    <br>
    <b>file:</b><br>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %><br>
    <small>Доступные форматы: xml, xmlx</small>
    <br>
    <br>
    <%= submit_tag "Load", :onclick => "submitAndTemporarilyDisable(this)" %>
<% end %>
```

And here is my controller:

```
def import_cash_payments
      selects
      employer_id = current_employer.id
      datas = params.slice(:city_id, :region_id, :date)
      file = File.new(params[:file]) # HERE IS ERROR... File is nil, but why?
      file.save
      import = Import.new(datas, employer_id, file)
      import.run
    end
```

Error that I get:

```
can't convert nil into String
```

Error is given befor submit, i cant even press button, cuz view doesnt work.

Comment: File is a ruby class which will expect a particular set of attributes to be passed to it's `.new` method.  The attributes you get through in params probably have the wrong names.  What do you have in `params[:file]`? (your log file will show you)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what i've done in the past, to do just this by hand (as opposed to using Paperclip or similar).  The key to this is that you pull the data from the file parameter with `.read` and then write it into the new file you're creating with `.write`.  You need to give it a filename too, i'm using a timestamp here.

```
#you need to make a filename for the file in tmp.  Let's use a timestamp
@filename = File.join("/tmp", Time.now.to_f)
@file = File.open(@filename,"w"){|f| f.write params[:file].read}
```